# Changing variable value of linked list node in Java.

Tags: java, memory, data-structures, linked-list

In the code below, how come when I change the node variable two to null, the first node variable one still has a next value of 2?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node one = new Node(1);
    Node two = new Node(2);
    one.next = two;

    System.out.println(one.val + ", " + one.next.val); //1, 2
    two = null; //one.next.val is still 2
    System.out.println(one.val + ", " + one.next.val); //1 ,2
}

static class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    public Node(int val) {
    this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you only set the _reference_ to ``null``. You don't delete the object that was created using ``new Node(2)`` The object that ``two`` referred to is still existing (accessible using ``one.next``).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create :

```
Node one = new Node(1);
Node two = new Node(2);
```

You create two `Node` objects i.e. `Node(1)` and `Node(2)` and two references (i.e. `one` and `two`)

Now when you do

```
one.next = two;
```

You are not creating any new object but a new reference to the `Node(2)`object.

So now you have two objects ( `Node(1)` and `Node(2)` ) and three references i.e. `one`, `two` and `one.next`.

When you do

```
two = null;
```

**It deletes reference `two`. But note that you can still access the `Node(2)` object via its second reference i.e. `one.next`.**

Comment: got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the reference of one.next to null in order for it to not exist. The line

```
two = null;
```

sets the object two to point to null and no longer to previous node with val 2, but it continues to exist and the node one still points to it.

```
one.next = null;
```

Once you point the one.next to null there is no more reference to the object and the object is lost and collected by the garbage collector later on